# Is there a way for me to create a mock file that counts how many times it is opened?

Tags: java, security, exe

I know it is weird question, but I would like to know how many members of my organization would open a file sent to them via email so I can teach them more about security and its importance. Ultimately, I would like to create an executable file that simply counts how many times it was opened so I can show them in the meeting I am conducting soon. It seems easy, but I don't know where to begin.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This isn't easy.

Comment: Fair enough. If it's too difficult, I won't worry about it. I was just curious if it can be done with simple code.